# Import data macro add new column

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to using macros on excel

I basically have created a master sheet which will gather all information inputted into a form. Once the person completes the form they will need to import this form to the master sheet (the master sheet will gather all entries).

Every time a new user has imported data i want the master sheet to be able to have new columns based on the newly imported data.

I have done the below:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("C6:C12").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e7").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("g16:g29").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e16").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("o19:o24").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e33").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("o29:o32").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e40").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("o36:o45").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e45").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("c34:c36").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e58").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("c38:c40").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e62").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("c42:c44").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e66").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("c50:c52").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e72").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("c54:c56").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e76").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Sheets(2).Range("o50:o54").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_MASTER").Range("e81").PasteSpecial
    OpenBook.Close False

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This just imports the first data...however when i import the second file it overwrites the entry.

Please could you help me and explain as clearly as possible on what code i can use to add new entries

FYI:

The master sheet I want it to look like this

```
  A       B       C      
5:NAME| SURNAME| DOB
6:LUCY| BELLS| 15/02/1980
7:CHARLOTTE|JULIE|15/02/1980
8:LUKE|WELIS|15/02/1980
```

Thank you,

Comment: Sounds like you need to find the last column? `Dim lastColumn as Long`, `lastColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WW_Master").Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`.

Comment: It looks like you are copying from a specific cell, to a specific cell. So naturally, anything previously entered in that cell will be overwritten. Search for tips on how to find the first empty column to paste your data.

Comment: @BigBen could you let me know how i can flip this to be persons on each row and titles across the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BigBen said you need to find the empty end column. This can be done in VBA using

```
ColumnNumber = ws.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```

which is the same as a user pressing Ctrl-Left from cell XFD7. Take a look at [With .. End With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) blocks to avoid repeating the name of objects. [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/using-arrays) can be useful too, for example -

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Get_Data_From_File()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "WW_MASTER"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbForm As Workbook, wsForm As Worksheet
    Dim sFilename As String, map As Variant
    Dim iTargetCol As Integer, t0 As Single, msg As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    iTargetCol = ws.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    sFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import", _
                           FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

    If sFilename = "False" Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical
    End If

    ' master row, form range, form sheet
    map = Array( _
        7, "C6:C12", 1, _
        16, "G16:G29", 1, _
        33, "O19:O24", 2, _
        40, "O29:O32", 2, _
        45, "C36:C45", 2, _
        58, "C34:C36", 2, _
        62, "C38:C40", 2, _
        66, "C42:C44", 2, _
        72, "C50:C52", 2, _
        76, "C54:C56", 2, _
        81, "O50:O54", 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    t0 = Timer

    ' copy using mapping rules
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer

    Set wbForm = Workbooks.Open(sFilename, False, True) ' read only
    For i = LBound(map) To UBound(map) Step 3
        n = map(i + 2) ' sheet no
        wbForm.Sheets(n).Range(map(i + 1)).Copy
        ws.Cells(map(i), iTargetCol).PasteSpecial
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wbForm.Close False

    ' end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    msg = "Imported into column " & iTargetCol & vbCrLf & _
          "From " & sFilename
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Finished in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.00") & " secs"

End Sub
```

Or import into one row

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File2()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1" '"WW_MASTER"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbForm As Workbook, wsForm As Worksheet
    Dim sFilename As String, map As Variant
    Dim iTargetRow As Long, t0 As Single, msg As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    iTargetRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    sFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import", _
                           FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

    If sFilename = "False" Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical
    End If

    ' master row, form range, form sheet
    map = Array( _
        1, "D6", 1, _
        2, "C8:C14", 1, _
        9, "O19:O24", 2)
    '    40, "O29:O32", 2, _
    '    45, "C36:C45", 2, _
    '    58, "C34:C36", 2, _
    '    62, "C38:C40", 2, _
    '    66, "C42:C44", 2, _
    '    72, "C50:C52", 2, _
    '    76, "C54:C56", 2, _
    '    81, "O50:O54", 2)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    t0 = Timer

    ' copy using mapping rules
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer, k As Integer, var As Variant, rng As Range

    Set wbForm = Workbooks.Open(sFilename, False, True) ' read only
    For i = LBound(map) To UBound(map) Step 3
        n = map(i + 2) ' sheet no
        Set rng = wbForm.Sheets(n).Range(map(i + 1))
        If rng.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ws.Cells(iTargetRow, map(i)) = rng.Value
        Else
            var = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng)
            ' fill columns
            For k = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
               ws.Cells(iTargetRow, map(i) + k - 1) = var(k)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wbForm.Close False

    ' end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    msg = "Imported into Row " & iTargetRow & vbCrLf & _
          "From " & sFilename
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Finished in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.00") & " secs"

End Sub
```

Comment: @exceling Which columns C6:C12 to cols 7 to 13, G16:G29 to col 17 to 30 etc ?

Comment: @Exceling you need to define in the map array where on the form each column of data comes from for example ; column 1 (name) is cell("A4") on sheet1 of form, column 2 (Surname) is cell("C10") on sheet1, Column 3 (DOB) is cell("G12") on sheet 2 etc.

Comment: @excel Ok I have updated the code, transpose doesn't work for single cell range so I have added if-else block to deal with it. You can delete some of your comments now.

Comment: Hi, i am now trying to add the below to the array as i have a table on my template that i would like to import into the rows too

        26, "G9", 2, _
        27, "H9", 2, _
        28, "I9", 2, _
        29, "J9", 2, _
        30, "G10", 2, _
        31, "H10", 2, _
        32, "I10", 2, _
        33, "J10", 2, _
        34, "G11", 2, _
        35, "H11", 2, _
        36, "I11", 2, _

am i able to add the above as its is giving me an error of too many lines? thank you @cdp1802

Comment: @excel How many lines do you have, you can put many mappings on one line but it is harder to spot the mistakes. Try putting them in pairs, 6 items per line.